# IF and else if to paste data into three different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy rows onto three different sheets based on criteria in column AZ. I can get the first IF statement to work but the else ifs copy the information not in the first row of the designated sheet but where the previous sheet ended.

Here is what I have

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Cell As Range

With Sheets(2)

    For Each Cell In .Range("AZ2:AZ" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AZ").End(xlUp).Row)
        
        If Cell.Value = 1 Then
            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("2X4").Rows(Cell.Row)
        ElseIf Cell.Value = 2 Then
            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("2X6").Rows(Cell.Row)
        ElseIf Cell.Value = 3 Then
            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("2X6H").Rows(Cell.Row)
        End If
   Next Cell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: this seems to be pretty simple and clear code - what exactly 'doesnt work' about the second two cases?

Comment: It is not copying anything into the 2x6 sheet or the 2x6H sheet

Comment: no errors, it just doesn't copy them over?

Comment: correct. it is not copying them over, only for the 2x4 sheet it does. I thought I did something incorrect with the code because it will run just not copy it over for the 2x6 and 2x6H sheets

Comment: i would say it's not your code but is some other factor like your worksheet's not named exactly the same as specified above

Comment: just some ideas: are those sheets all in the same workbook? are those rows in the destination hidden? is it all named correctly?

Comment: Wow I feel dumb, that fixed the copy issue, but now it copies it starting in row 272 which is where the 2x4 sheet left off

Comment: what exactly did you fix/change?

Comment: the sheet names were not an exact match

Comment: so you want each paste to start at the first open cell in each of the destinations?

Comment: I need it to start in row A2 for each sheet

Comment: simple way would be create 3 variables and just increment them separately as values are added.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up on @Marcucciboy2's comment you could use something like this.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Cell As Range, v1, v2

v1 = Array("2X4", "2X6", "2X6H"): v2 = Array(2, 2, 2)

With Sheets(2)
    For Each Cell In .Range("AZ2:AZ" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AZ").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cell.Value = 1 Or Cell.Value = 2 Or Cell.Value = 3 Then
            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets(v1(Cell.Value - 1)).Range("A" & v2(Cell.Value - 1))
            v2(Cell.Value - 1) = v2(Cell.Value - 1) + 1
        End If
    Next Cell
End With

End Sub
```